# InDesign: Exporting CMYK doc as RGB

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf, print-production, color-conversion

If I want to export a CMYK document as RGB, is it best to go into every swatch, and every placed link, and make sure all the colours are set to RGB before exporting?

Or can I just set it to `sRGB` under the `Color Conversion` section when exporting a PDF? Will that be enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CMYK gamut fits entirely into the RGB gamut. So, every color *possible* with CMYK is also *possible* with RGB. You won't get "clipped" colors moving from CMYK -> RGB. 
Vice versa is **not** true. RGB -> CMYK *will* possibly "clip" colors due to the smaller CMYK gamut.

[image]
<sup>[  image from: [https://www.myprintsouth.com/](https://www.myprintsouth.com/resources/blog_articles.html/article/2018/01/22/designing-for-print-rgb-vs-cmyk) ]</sup>

In general, this comes down to how finicky you are about color. For most, just exporting a CMYK document to PDF and setting the output intent to RGB is sufficient.

I create a ton of CMYK documents for press and merely export directly to an RGB PDF for email/web distribution. I've never had a reason to complain or to *specifically* build RGB documents.